ImportError: Cannot initialize a EGL device display
I am trying to train a robot to open doors using mujoco on Linux but it's displays this error and i am not sure what it is about as i am just starting out and I dont have any gpu except the built-in.
this is the code i am trying to run:
import time
import os
import gym
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
import robosuite as suite
from robosuite.wrappers import GymWrapper
if name == 'main':
if not os.path.exists("tmp/td3"):
    os.makedirs("tmp/td3")

env_name = "Door"

env = suite.make(
    env_name,
    robots=["Panda"],
    controller_configs=suite.load_controller_config(default_controller="JOINT_VELOCITY"),
    has_renderer=False,
    horizon=300,  #how many time steps before episode ends
    reward_shaping=True,  #the robot will be rewarded along the way
    control_freq=20
)

env = GymWrapper(env)

I honestly have not tried anything since I am unable to find any suitable solutions for this and I dont want to try something that won't work, might mess something else so please help
